# Checkbox binding in not working in WPF ListView Cell Template

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl1 and another UserControl2 in UserControl1.
In the User Control2, I have a listview.

I am getting a DataSet from DB and I want to bind the "MyTable" with listview. So i did as shown below in
the code behind.

```
UserControl1.UserControl2.lstview.ItemsSource = DataSet.Tables["MyTable"].DefaultView;
```

The above method is working. But the problem is, there is a checkbox as a cell template in one column.

```
 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isok, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="20" Height="15" />
      </DataTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

[isok is a bit type column in the MyTable]

But when i update the isok column through code, it is not reflecting in the UI. ie, checkbox is not checked or unchecked.

So maybe that could be the problem of not setting Binding Mode to 2 way. So I did as shown below. But no data is displaying in the listview when i did as shown below !!!

What could be the problem here ???

```
Binding b = new Binding("DataSet.Tables");
b.Source = DataSet.Tables["MyTable"].DefaultView;
b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
UserControl1.UserControl2.lstview.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
```

I am updating the column value as shown below

```
  DataView dv = (DataView)lstview.ItemsSource;
 foreach (DataRow dr in dv.Rows)
        {
            dr["isok"] = isselected;
        }
```

NB : Here no MVVM

Answer (score 0):

DataRow doesnt implement INotifyPropertyChanged and therefore when you change a property the UI will not get notified.

User DataRowView instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

**EDIT:**

```
foreach (DataRowView tempRowView in myDataTable.DefaultView)
{
  ...
}
```

Items in myDataTable.DefaultView may be casted directly to DataRowView.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how to get DataRowView from listview itemsource ? It is DataView only ?